# Is there any way to remove an element from the list if it 's closest div contains specific class?

Tags: jquery

I have `div2`, `div4` and `div6` in a variable. How can I remove all divs from the variable if its closest div contains the `test2` class?

```
<div class="test1">
  <div id="div1"> 
    <div id="div2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test2">
  <div id="div3"> 
    <div id="div4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="test2">
  <div id="div5"> 
    <div id="div6">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you explain more understandable?